# System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController not defined vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, service

in visual studio i have added 
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController
but get an error saying its not defined.

everywhere on net says it should work.

but it doesnt why not

Comment: hi dont know who marked negative but please elaberate so i can improve my questions for next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the fix is to go to the project properties
references tab
and add
System.ServiceProcess

then it no longer errors.